# How to get range of custom word in my VS Code Extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to get the range of a custom word in my VS Code extension, if I hover on it, and if the line of text matches a pattern. This is what I've written so far:

```
vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('.mylanguage', {
    provideHover(document, position, token) {
        // define `hoverRange` somewhere here
        const hoverLineText = document.lineAt(position.line).text;
        const pattern = new RegExp("\\w+\\s{0,}\\(.{0,}\\s{0,}\\)");
        if(pattern.test(hoverLineText)){
            hoverRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, pattern);
        }
        console.log(hoverRange);
        //etc. ...
```

I am expecting that, if you write in the editor something like `myFunction (  )`, and you hover on any position of that string (e.g. even on the whitespace), the console will output `hoverRange`, which will take into account the position of the closing parenthesis `)`, as well.

However, if I hover on the whitespace, nothing is outputted to the console. Instead, I need to hover on `myFunction`, so that I can get the whole range of the string.

How can I make my VS Code extension treat `myFunction (  )` as one single word?

Comment: `{0,}` is `*`, instead of `getWordRangeAtPosition` calculate the offset of the string `myFunction (  )` start and end and convert that to a range, why do you need to duplicate the regex, why have you defined `hoverRange` outside the `provideHover` function

Comment: @rioV8 My bad, I just changed `hoverRange` to be defined inside `provideHover`. I can calculate the offset of the string, and convert to that range, but that results in the same thing as above. I would still have to hover on `myFunction` to get the new range.

Comment: is the hover provider called in all occasions you want

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, the provider is called in all occasions I want. The only issue is that I don't know how to make VS Code recognize a custom word.

Comment: if the regex matches somewhere in the line, find the start and end of the match and create a range for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
let disposable3 = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('plaintext', {
    provideHover(document, position) {

        let hoverRange;
        const hoverLineText = document.lineAt(position.line).text;
        const pattern = new RegExp("\\w+\\s*\\(.*\\s*\\)");

        if (pattern.test(hoverLineText)){
            hoverRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, pattern);
            if (hoverRange) return new vscode.Hover(document.getText(hoverRange), new vscode.Range(position, position));
            else return null;
        }
        else return null;
    }
});
context.subscriptions.push(disposable3);
```

As you can see the hover works over spaces.  But the regex is too lenient so that it does pick up things like

`if (asdasdasd)`
`while(adasd)`

since those look like a function calls too.

[image: hover with range]

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. It is strange why my code continues to work the same even after following your example. I only get the hover text if I hover on `myFunction` - not if I hover on the whitespace. I will wait for another answer, and if there's no other answer that can solve my issue directly, I will mark yours as correct, as it was helpful still.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand - it works for me as you can see.  For testing I did change it to a `plaintext` .txt file.  Does my code  work in a .txt file for you?

Comment: Yeah, your code works perfectly in a .txt file. I am logging to console to debug my code, and it seems that `position` does not get logged if I hover on whitespaces, or other characters (non-letters) that are separated from the letters with whitespace characters. For example, `position` will get logged if I hover on the parenthesis in `myFunction(`, but not if I hover on the parenthesis in `myFunction  (  `. Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: I see you had `'.mylanguage'` in your code.  That argument is a languageID.  If you go to the language in the lower right corner of vscode and click it, it would be what is in parentheses for your language.  It isn't a file extension.